# How to enable debug logs in OpenSwan?

Tags: ipsec, openswan

I use OpenSwan IPSec tunnel on CentOS 6.7.

I have added the following configuration in <s>`/etc/ipsec.secrets`</s> according to this link: http://linux.die.net/man/5/ipsec.conf

```
config setup

plutodebug=all

plutostderrlog=/var/log/openswan.log
```

Unfortunately I can not see logs in openswan.log.

What I have missed?

Comment: Look in your system logs for any relevant info.

Answer (score 10):

Required to add the configuration to file `/etc/ipsec.conf`

```
# basic configuration
config setup
        plutodebug=all

        plutostderrlog=/var/log/openswan.log
```

Comment: On 1/12/18, with `strongSwan 5.3.5`, adding these lines and restarting the server reports both keywords as deprecated. I have not yet found a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is an old question, `plutodebug` is deprecated. `charondebug` must be used. See https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConfigSetupSection for the differences.